# How to create a pdf with tiff or png images with ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, xfa

The use of xfa inside pdf isn’t only for creating forms
Short : I need valid test cases for a new xfa ᴘᴅꜰ reader, but couldn’t found anyone nor I could find how to use ghostscript in order to create such test cases in batch.

The point is I don’t know how to build the extra information ghostscript should handle without an hex editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghostscript doesn't handle XFA at all, neither on input nor in output, you cannot use Ghostscript to create XFA files.

Nor does Ghostscript (currently) create PDF files which solely consist of an image. Even if it did, these wouldn't be PNG or TIFF images, as those file formats are not directly supported by PDF. The next release of Ghostscript will contain devices which produce PDF files where the content is a rendered bitmap image created from the input. But they won't be either PNG or TIFF file format.

Note that XFA has been removed from the PDF 2.0 specification (hardly surprising as its XML not PDF format).

Comment: Ghostscript doen’t knows anything about the xml format, but it can add a from from an xml file. So at least, I need to know how to do this.

Comment: No, it can't (translating here to what I think you mean) add a form from an xml file. The pdfwrite device (not Ghostscript but a specific device) generates a certain amount of xml internally but that's not the same thing. Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device do support the pdfmark operator and most of the keys will work so you **might** be able to do what you want, though I'm highly doubtful you can create an XFA that way.